# Datatables library not working in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-3

I'm trying the Datatables Library on CodeIgniter 3, but it doesn't work in CI3. I've tried [this example](http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/) in CodeIgniter 2 and it works perfectly but I want this library on CodeIgniter 3.

What do I need to change in order for it to work with CodeIgniter 3?

Comment: The term "datatable" is ambiguous. In .NET, it's a class that represents a table of in-memory data. In component based MVC frameworks like JSF and Wicket, it's an UI component that dynamically renders a HTML table based on a collection. For jQuery DataTables plugin, please use [jquery-datatables] tag.

Comment: thanks for your advice!

Comment: Check [this topic](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/25511/new-codeigniter-datatables-1-10-library) on their forums.

Comment: you have doing this with Code Igniter 3? @Tpojka ....

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: the list of datatables isn't display... but in CI 2,it work perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create Person_model.php in model directory

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
     class Person_model extends CI_Model {
           var $table = 'persons';
           var $column = array('firstname','lastname','gender','address','dob');
          var $order = array('id' => 'desc');

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

     private function _get_datatables_query()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->column as $item)
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value'])
                ($i===0) ? $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']) : $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            $column[$i] = $item;
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

create controller file Person.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Person extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('person_model','person');
    }

     public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('person_view');
    }

    public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->person->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $person->firstName;
            $row[] = $person->lastName;
            $row[] = $person->gender;
            $row[] = $person->address;
            $row[] = $person->dob;
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->person->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->person->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

and the last create for view. person_view.php at views directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ajax CRUD with Bootstrap modals and Datatables</title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="container">
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
          <th style="width:125px;">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')?>"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var save_method; //for save method string
    var table;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      table = $('#table').DataTable({

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        {
          "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
          "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

      });
    });


    function reload_table()
    {
      table.ajax.reload(null,false); //reload datatable ajax
    }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the SQL to create table :

create database crud;
   use crud;
   CREATE TABLE `persons` (
   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `firstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gender` enum('male','female') DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;